# How to get query result from gem-mysql2?

Tags: mysql, ruby

Why don't I get the result of the select query when I do the below?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'mysql2'
require 'awesome_print'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "example.com", :username => "x", :password => "x", :database => "hd")

r = client.query("select CLIENT_ID from CLIENT where EMAIL='x@x.com'")

ap r
```

The output is

```
$ ./hd.rb 
/usr/share/gems/gems/awesome_print-1.0.2/lib/awesome_print/formatter.rb:355: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
#<Mysql2::Result:0x55fab9bfd880
    @query_options = {
                          :as => :hash,
                       :async => false,
               :cast_booleans => false,
              :symbolize_keys => false,
           :database_timezone => :local,
        :application_timezone => nil,
                  :cache_rows => true,
               :connect_flags => 2147525124,
                        :cast => true,
                :default_file => nil,
               :default_group => nil,
                        :host => "example.com",
                    :username => "x",
                    :password => "x",
                    :database => "hd"
    }
```

Comment: Look at the project's README on [github](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2). It has a complete usage example right there.

Comment: `ap r.to_h` should do it [`Enumerable#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h)

Comment: @Max You mean the two files in `examples/`? They don't help me sadly.

Comment: @engineersmnky Then I get `wrong element type Hash (expected array) (TypeError)`

Comment: Sorry should have been `ap r.to_a`

Comment: @engineersmnky If you post than, then I will accept it for sure =) Is it because it outputs both an array and a hash?

Comment: @Louise I don't mean in examples, I mean if you just scroll down on that page I linked to. It says "Usage" and shows how you can iterate over the query results with `each`.